# Adding data to firebase in order of newest post (React js)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add 'posts' into firebase db but it doesn't appear in order, it randomly inserts data into the database, is there a way to insert then in order? So whenever someone posts it appears first.

I'm using this

```
db.collection('posts').add({
            
        });
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documents in Firestore don't really have a set order.  In the Firebase console, they are displayed in lexicographic order using the ID of the document.  When you use `add()`, the client will generate a random ID for the document.  As such, the document will appear in some random order in the Firebase console.

If you want time-based ordering of documents, you should add a timestamp field to the document.  Usually applications use a [server timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) as a field value to generate a timestamp on the server.  Then, you can [order a query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data) using the field to get the documents in timestamp order.

Comment: thank you! I used the server timestamp with the order by timestamp function and it works so well!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore does not have any built-in ordering for documents. If you want to order the documents on creation data, you should make sure the documents have a field with that creation data in there. You can then tell the Firebase console to sort on the value of that field.

If the accuracy of this field is important, it is recommend to [use `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp) to set it, and to validate its value in security rules, as client-side timestamps can be manipulated by the client.